# NativeScript Angular: How do I redirectTo child nested route?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using NativeScript Angular, and can't figure out how to setup the default view to use a `children` nested route path.

The easiest way to convey what I'm trying to accomplish is to look at my playground here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WvQnzu&v=581

Open up `app/home/home-routing.module.ts` and on line 9 you can see where I'm trying to re-direct the initial page view to load the `first` child component in the `<router-outlet>` defined in `home.component.html`

I can load the child component in the nested `<router-outlet>` by clicking a button OR by using the programatic `this.routerExtensions.navigate()` (see `home.component.ts` line 47)

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the initial load of the `HomeComponent` display the `FirstComponent` child in the nested `<router-outlet>`??

I just want to use this *custom* tab navigation, and load a component when the tab navigation item is clicked.

**Extra credit:** I see `outlet` used in routes as well as this funky `/<route>(<outlet>:<route>)` named outlet notation.  Example: [modal-navigation-ng] e2e app[1](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/e2e/modal-navigation-ng/app/app.routing.ts).  Is this notation/mechanism documented anywhere? I kinda get what's going on but seems like some black-box/magic.  I can't fully grasp the concept by simply looking at the [e2e example app](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/tree/master/e2e/modal-navigation-ng/app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple levels of absolute redirect is not supported by Angular.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25254

An easy fix is to use relative redirect

**app-routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "home", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" },
    { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" }
];
```

**home-routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "", component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
            { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'first', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]
    }
];
```